# How to update column with ORMLite

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I have an already created database for Android application and I'm using ORMLite for query to SQLLite.

I have added a column in category and I want to insert data in that column.
I have row, e.g.

```
catId=5 catname="food" catType=?
```

I want to update `catType` on the basis of `catId`. How can I update this `catType` column with the `catId` in ORMLite.

I am using this approach:

```
Dao<Category, Integer> catDao = getHelper().getCategoryDao();
QueryBuilder<Category, Integer> queryBuilder = catDao.queryBuilder();
queryBuilder.where().eq("categoryId", 5);
PreparedQuery<Category> pq = queryBuilder.prepare();
Category category = catDao.queryForFirst(pq);
category.setCategoryType("BarType");
catDao.createOrUpdate(category);
```

Please provide me a better solution.

Comment: what is wrong with this one ?

Comment: njzk2, it is slower because it does 2 database operations instead of 1

Answer (score 73):

> I want to update catType on the basis of catId. How can I update this catType column with the catId in ORMLite.

[ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) also supports an [`UpdateBuilder`](http://ormlite.com/docs/update-builder).  Here's how you could use it:

```
UpdateBuilder<Category, Integer> updateBuilder = catDao.updateBuilder();
// set the criteria like you would a QueryBuilder
updateBuilder.where().eq("categoryId", 5);
// update the value of your field(s)
updateBuilder.updateColumnValue("catType" /* column */, "BarType" /* value */);
updateBuilder.update();
```

See the [`UpdateBuilder` docs](http://ormlite.com/docs/update-builder) for more examples.

Answer (score 4):

```
Dao<Category, Integer> catDao = getHelper().getCategoryDao();
List <Category> categoryList = catDao.queryForAll();
for (Category c: categoryList ) {
    c.setCategoryType("BarType");
    catDao.update(c);
}
```

Comment: Concurrent updates to the same entity (but on different fields) may override each others.